# Android custom popup menu with subtitles

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

After selecting a menu item I must to open a list where in a few lines a subtitle appears, how can I do? I'm developing for Android 4.x

[image]

My code in menu.xml

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
    android:orderInCategory="11111"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
         <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/action_settings1"
            android:titleCondensed="standard"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/action_settings2"
            />
         <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/action_settings2"
            />
    </menu>
</item>
```

I do not know how to add subtitles

Comment: you may refer this answer:[Refer This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327777/android-actionbar-spinner-selected-item-subtitle-and-dropdown-list

Comment: In this example there is a spinner on the left, I must develop a menu on the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use ActionBar. Custom dropdown list can be set by

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      /**
       * View displayed inside the Action Bar
       */
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View resultView = convertView;
        if (resultView == null) {
          resultView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_main, null);
        }

        return resultView;
      }

      /**
      * View Displayed inside list of possible options
      */
      @Override
      public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View resultView = convertView;

        if (resultView == null) {
          resultView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down, null);
        }

        return resultView;
      }

    }
```

and then

```
getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(new MyAdapter(), listener);
```

The other things, like custom back icon, you can achieve making styles for your ActionBar.